# KahaDb properties in Grails

Tags: grails, activemq-classic

Using ActiveMQ in Grails through JMS plugin I cannot figure how to set KahaDb persistence properties.

Tried something like:

```
amq.broker(useJmx: true, persistent: true) {
    amq.transportConnectors() {
        amq.transportConnector(uri: "tcp://0.0.0.0:61616")
    }
    amq.persistenceAdapter() {
        amq.kahaDB(directory:${application.config.grails.moviesxd.activemq.kahadb},
                   checksumJournalFiles:true,
                   checkForCorruptJournalFiles:true,
                   ignoreMissingJournalfiles:true)          
    }
}
```

But i get

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Namespace prefix: kahadb is not bound to a URI
```

Seems like kahadb prefix is not recognized but i cannot find documentation anywhere on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing the equivalent of

```
xmlns:amq='http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core'
```

which would be

```
xmlns amq:'http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core'
```

(see the [reference docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/spring.html#theBeanBuilderDSLExplained) for more info - search for "Using Spring Namespaces")

so the whole conversion would be

```
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory

xmlns amq:'http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core'

amq.broker(useJmx: true, persistent: true) {
    amq.transportConnectors {
        amq.transportConnector(uri: 'tcp://0.0.0.0:61616')
    }
    amq.persistenceAdapter {
        amq.kahaDB(directory: application.config.grails.moviesxd.activemq.kahadb,
                   checksumJournalFiles: true,
                   checkForCorruptJournalFiles: true,
                   ignoreMissingJournalfiles: true)
    }
}

amq.connectionFactory(id: 'amqConnectionFactory', brokerURL: 'vm://localhost')

jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory, ref('amqConnectionFactory'))
```

Comment: Thanks Burt ... i was using the activemq without problems until i try to configure KahDb parameters. I mean i was actually using the amq prefix and it was working ... i am probably missing the equivalent namespace for KahaDB as you said ... i'll try to find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround what i've done is to include an additional resources.xml and use standard and well documented XML properties as:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <amq:broker useJmx="true" persistent="true">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:persistenceAdapter>
            <amq:kahaDB directory="${grails.moviesxd.activemq.kahadb.path}" />
        </amq:persistenceAdapter>
    </amq:broker>

    <amq:connectionFactory id="amqConnectionFactory"
        brokerURL="vm://localhost" />

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

... but it's a piti i have to do this ... still will be great if i get an answer.